# How can I replicate a command name as an argument?

Tags: macros

I've searched for but not found an answer to this.

I am using two layers of `\newcommand`s to create symbols inline with text, using `\includegraphics`. (It's for music symbols.)

At present, I have this as the generic command:

```
\newcommand*{\inlineImage}[2]{\raisebox{#1pt}{\fbox{\includegraphics{__#2__}}}}
```

And then many commands of the form:

```
\newcommand*{\Eighth}{\inlineImage{0}{Eighth}}
\newcommand*{\Sixteenth}{\inlineImage{-1.5}{Sixteenth}}
```

This works, but it is cumbersome to type the same text twice during set up. Of course, I could employ a command with arguments in my document body, but I don't want to do that. Is there a way to replace the specific commands with something of the form:

```
\newcommand*{\Sixteenth}{\inlineImage{-1.5}{<thecommandname>}}
```

Comment: Try something like `\def\newnote#1{\edef\csname #1\endcsname\inlineImage{-1.5}{#1}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `etoolbox` package provides the `\csdef` command:

```
\newcommand*{\inlineImage}[2]{\raisebox{#1pt}{\fbox{\includegraphics{__#2__}}}}
\newcommand*\defnote[2]{\csdef{#1}{\inlineImage{#2}{#1}}}
```

Then use

```
\defnote{Eighth}{0}
\defnote{Sixteenth}{-1.5}
```

to create the macros `\Eighth` and `\Sixteenth` as you wanted.

Comment: LaTeX provides `\@namedef`.

Answer (score 4):

To make command from text use `\csname .. \endcsname` macros. For example, if you will write

```
\def\newnote#1{\expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname{\inlineImage{-1.5}{#1}}}
```

then commands like

```
\newnote{Fourth}
\newnote{Eighth}
\newnote{Sixteenth}
```

will define notes `\Fourth`, `\Eighth` and `\Sixteenth`, which will insert appropriate images.

Comment: Thanks Eddy_Em: this gets me a lot closer! However, part of the problem is that I need to adjust the raisebox variable. It was daft of me not to make that explicit with my example, which I have now corrected. How can I adapt the above answer to do this? This is beyond my abilities at the moment!

Comment: It may be noteworthy that you can also do `\expandafter\newcommand\csname #1\endcsname` to still have the possibilities to use `\newcommand` syntax.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, `\newcommand` is overhead for such simple task.